# Почему сложение цифр числа не работает правильно?

Tags: c, while

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int N,sum=0; 
while (1)
{
do
{
printf("Введите натур. число: ");
scanf("%d",&N);
} 
while (N==0||N<0); 
while (N>0){
    sum+=N%10;
    N/=10;
}

printf("Сумма цифр числа = %d\n\n",sum);
getchar();
}
}
```

Выдаётся такое:

[image: баг.png]

Должно быть, по идее, 9, а не 18 (хотя приметно то, что 1+8=9).

Comment: Мы же с Вами уже выяснили, что такие переменные как `sum` надо обнулять перед очередным вычислением.

Comment: @Igor Всё, работает, спасибо.